# How to change language of Fingerprint Popup in Ionic4?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I'm using cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio plugin in my ionic4 project.

I want to display fingerprint popup content in different language depend upon our app langauge.

This plugin support multi-language support but want to know that how to use it for both Android and iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that you have to use

```
npm install --save @ngx-translate
```

sometime direct language translations occurs issues because it does not convert correct word ,so in that situation you have to keep separately

> https://enappd.com/blog/how-to-translate-in-ionic-4-globalization-internationalization-and-localization/11/